# Unable to craft Mythril anvil and the Twins

Tags: terraria

How do I get the recipe for the mythril anvil? When I speak to guide and look on crafting it says I have all the ingredients but it won't let me build it when I need it.

The same goes for the twins, it won't let me make it when I have the stuff to do so

Comment: You probably aren't using the required tool to make it. For instance the mythril anvil needs you to be standing at a lead/iron anvil

Comment: Yeah I stand near the iron anvil but I can't create it and the space gun I have all the requirements but it won't let me craft it

Comment: Try dropping and picking up the ingredients again, or toggling between show all and show available. This will effectively "refresh"

Answer (score 2):

To make a [Mythril Anvil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mythril_Anvil), you need to have 10 Mythril bars in your inventory (made from 40 mythril at a furnace). Then, stand next to an iron or lead anvil and you will be able to craft it!

When you say you want to craft 'The Twins', I assume you mean their spawning item, the [Mechanical Eye](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mechanical_Eye). This requires the Mythril Anvil to craft, so you will need to make that first.

You only need 3 lenses, 5 iron/lead bars and 5 soul of lights to craft the Mechanical Eye. Stand next to a Mythril anvil and you will be able to craft it!

If you are unable to craft these items, restart Terraria to make sure it is not broken.